# How to do a t-test on rare events distributions?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, t-test, rare-events

I have a dataset, which contains several features (`feature_1`, `feature_2`, ..., `feature_n`) and a `y` `binary` feature.

I would like to check if `mean`s of the distributions for all `n` features between the `y==1` & `y==0` groups are different

The problem is that the `y==1` is really small (around 25 observations) whereas the `y==0` group has around 900 observations.

Is there an alternative way to do that, apart from the `t-test` ?

Comment: What’s wrong with the t-test?

Comment: @Dave The`y==1` group has very few observations

Comment: So what’s wrong with the t-test?

Comment: Doesnt small sample size correspond to low power ?

Comment: That’s true for every other test, too, and it should be. As you get more observations, you are better able to pin down the true value.

Comment: Does it make sense to do something like oversampling (by using e.g. SMOTE) and then do the t-test ?

Comment: Frank Harrell is a member of this Stack and the founding chairman of biostatistics at Vanderbilt. I like this tweet of his about SMOTE (though his context is different): https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en. Anyway, there is no need to SMOTE; t-testing would be perfectly fine unless you have some other reservation about that method.

Comment: If you have too little power for the individual t-tests, you could try a logistic regression with the binary feature as response. That will indicate if at least some of the features are related to the $y$, but maybe not which of them ...